# How to remove Group of CSS2DObject from the scene

Tags: css, three.js

I have a dynamic `msg_arr` array of strings that I want to visualize, and I want to remove the old *errs* `Group` of `CSS2DObject` from the scene before creating the new errors `Group`.

The problem in my case is that the new `CSS2DObject`s are added perfectly to the `Group`, but the **reset**: `this.scene.remove(this.errs);` is not working well!

Should I remove and create a new `CSS2DRenderer`??

Can you please tell me how can I be sure of resetting the whole old `Group` before creating the new one? thanks in advance.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, errs;

/**
 ErrVisu class
*/
class ErrVisu{
    constructor(scene){
        this.scene = scene;
    }
    
    visuError=(x, y, errs)=>{
        const x_mm = y * 0.8 - 8.8;
        const y_mm = 2.5;
        const z_mm = x * 0.8 - 2.4;

        const circle = document.createElement('div');
        circle.id = "circle";
        circle.innerHTML = "!";
        
        const objectCSS = new THREE.CSS2DObject(circle);
        objectCSS.position.set(x_mm, y_mm, z_mm);
        objectCSS.name = 'exc_' + x + y;
        errs.add(objectCSS);
    }
    
    errsIface = (msg_arr) => {
        this.scene.remove(this.errs);
        this.errs = new THREE.Group();
        this.errs.name = "errors";
        
        for (let k in msg_arr) {
            let p_xx_yy = msg_arr[k].split("_");
            let x = Number(p_xx_yy[1]);
            let y = Number(p_xx_yy[2]);
            this.visuError(x, y, this.errs);
        }
        this.scene.add(this.errs);
    }
} 
/**
 Create the scene, camera, renderer
*/
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x21252d);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 1;
  camera.position.y = 4;
  camera.position.z = 5;
  scene.add(camera);
  
  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
  document.body.appendChild( labelRenderer.domElement );

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, labelRenderer.domElement);
  
  errs = new ErrVisu(scene);
  let msg_arr_ = [ "p_06_08" ];
  errs.errsIface(msg_arr_);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
#circle {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff5500;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blinkingBackground 0.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingBackground {
  0% {
opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
opacity: 0.1;
  }
  75% {
opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ( [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74723471) ) was to create an array of `CSS2DObject`s and to remove the items of that array from the scene rather than combining the Objects in a Group!:

```js
errs.forEach((item) => {
    this.scene.remove(item);
});         
errs = [];

visuError=(x, y, errs, scene)=>{
    const x_mm = y * 0.8 - 8.8;
    const y_mm = 2.5;
    const z_mm = x * 0.8 - 2.4;

    const circle = document.createElement('div');
    circle.id = "circle";
    circle.innerHTML = "!";
    
    const objectCSS = new CSS2DObject(circle);
    objectCSS.position.set(x_mm, y_mm, z_mm);
    objectCSS.name = 'exc_' + x + y;

    scene.add(objectCSS);
    errs.push(objectCSS);
}
```