# Reset Function for CSS2DRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use the following class to create my scene, camera, renderer, and `CSS2DRenderer`.

I want to add a function to **reset** (delete and add again) my `CSS2DRenderer` to remove any previously rendered `CSS2DObject`, can you please tell me how can I do that properly? thanks in advance.

```js
import {
    Scene,
    Color,
    Vector3,
    AxesHelper,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    WebGLRenderer,
    DirectionalLight,
    HemisphereLight,
    AmbientLight,
    sRGBEncoding
} from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { CSS2DRenderer } from "three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js";
// import Stats from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';

export default class SceneCreator {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} container 
     */
    constructor(container) { 
        this.container = container;
        this.scene = null;
        this.camera = null;
        this.renderer = null;
        this.css_renderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
        // this.stats = new Stats();
        this.initScene();
    };

    initScene=()=> { 
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.background = new Color(0x21252d);

        this.createCamera();
        this.createLights();
        this.createControls();
        this.createRenderer();
        this.createAxe();
        // this.container.appendChild(this.stats.dom);
        this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            this.css_renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            // this.stats.update();
        });

        this.css_renderer.setSize( this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight );
        this.css_renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.css_renderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
        this.container.appendChild(this.css_renderer.domElement);
        
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize, false);
    }

    createCamera=()=> { 
        const fov = 60; 
        const near = 1;
        const far = 1000;
        const aspect_ratio = this.container.clientWidth/this.container.clientHeight
        this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect_ratio, near, far);
        this.camera.position.set(0.1, 10, 10);
        this.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    }

    createControls=()=> {
        /* Create Controls to allow for scene control */
        // const controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.container);
        const controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.css_renderer.domElement );
        controls.update();
    }

    createLights= ()=> {
        const mainLight = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5);
        mainLight.position.set(10, 10, 10);

        const hemisphereLight = new HemisphereLight(0xddeeff, 0x202020, 5);
        const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0x404040, 5);

        this.scene.add(mainLight, hemisphereLight, ambientLight);
    }

    createAxe = (len=1.6, pos=null) => { 
        const axis = new AxesHelper(len);

        const red   = new Color(0xff0000);
        const green = new Color(0x00ff00);
        const blue  = new Color(0x0000ff);
        
        axis.setColors(green, blue, red);

        if (pos === null) { 
            pos = new Vector3(8.0, 5.0, -3.2);
        }
        axis.position.x = pos.x;
        axis.position.y = pos.y;
        axis.position.z = pos.z;
       
        this.scene.add(axis);
    }
    createRenderer = ()=> {
        this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer('webgl2',{ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        this.renderer.setClearColor( 0xA3A3A3, 0 );
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
        this.renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    }

    onWindowResize = ()=> {
        this.camera.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight;
    
        // Update camera frustum
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.css_renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
    }

    getScene = () => { 
        return this.scene;
    }

    getCamera = () => { 
        return this.camera;
    }

    getRenderer = () => { 
        return this.renderer;
    }

    getCSS2DRenderer = () => { 
        return this.css_renderer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example hasn't created or added any `CSS2DObject`s to the scene. Looks like you haven't tried anything. But I recommend you store the objects you'll want to remove in their own array so you can just access them easily later. There's no need to destroy the renderer and re-build it. That'd just create unnecessary overhead.

```js
let allCSSItems = [];

const item1 = new CSS2DObject();
scene.add(item1);
allCSSItems.push(item1);

const item2 = new CSS2DObject();
scene.add(item2);
allCSSItems.push(item2);

// And so on... 

// Once you're ready to remove them from the scene, just use that array
allCSSItems.forEach((item) => {
    scene.remove(item);
});

// Clear array
allCSSItems = [];
```